# PyQt5, Qthread. Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

Good day. I can’t figure out why the program crashes with the error Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409). When one client connects, everything works fine, but when a second client connects, the program ends with an error. If you use the debugger, the program works fine.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import socket, json, threading
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from threading import Thread
class Ui_NetChat(QObject):
    clients = []
    nicknames = []

    def setupUi(self, NetChat):
        NetChat.setObjectName("NetChat")
        NetChat.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(NetChat)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.host_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.host_label.setObjectName("host_label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.host_label)
        self.port_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.port_label.setObjectName("port_label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.port_label)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.pl_log = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.pl_log.setObjectName("pl_log")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pl_log)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.startPB = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.startPB.setObjectName("startPB")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.startPB)
        self.stopPB = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stopPB.setObjectName("stopPB")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.stopPB)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        NetChat.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(NetChat)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        NetChat.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(NetChat)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(NetChat)

        self.startPB.clicked.connect(self.start_server)

    def reportProgress(self):
        print("Hello")

    def retranslateUi(self, NetChat):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        NetChat.setWindowTitle(_translate("NetChat", "MainWindow"))
        self.host_label.setText(_translate("NetChat", "HOST"))
        self.port_label.setText(_translate("NetChat", "PORT"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("NetChat", "Лог"))
        self.startPB.setText(_translate("NetChat", "Start"))
        self.stopPB.setText(_translate("NetChat", "Stop"))

    def start_server(self):
        HOST = 'localhost'
        PORT = 5555
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.bind((HOST,PORT))
        server.listen()
        ui.pl_log.appendPlainText(f"Севрер запущен на HOST = {HOST} и PORT = {PORT}")

        self.thread_client_conn = QThread()
        self.wait_client = ThreadWaitClient(server)
        self.wait_client.moveToThread(self.thread_client_conn)
        self.thread_client_conn.started.connect(self.wait_client.run)

        self.wait_client.thread_cleint.connect(self.window_log)
        self.wait_client.thread_cleint.connect(self.hendler)


        self.thread_client_conn.start()


    def window_log(self, message):
        ui.pl_log.appendPlainText(str(message))

    # I know that the error is in this part of the code Pat 1
    def hendler(self, client):
        self.thread_heandler = QThread()
        self.new_heandler_message = HeandlerMessage(client)
        self.new_heandler_message.moveToThread(self.thread_heandler)
        self.thread_heandler.started.connect(self.new_heandler_message.run)


        self.thread_heandler.start()


class ThreadWaitClient(QObject):
    thread_cleint = pyqtSignal(socket.socket)
    def __init__(self, server):
        super().__init__()
        self.server = server

    def run(self):
        print("Start ThreadWaitClient____RUN")
        while True:
            client, address = self.server.accept()
            self.thread_cleint.emit(client)

"""
# I know that the error is in this part of the code Pat 2
"""
class HeandlerMessage(QObject):
    def __init__(self, client):
        super().__init__()
        self.client = client

    def run(self):
        print("Heandler run ")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    NetChat = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_NetChat()
    ui.setupUi(NetChat)
    NetChat.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was trying to get multi-threaded software using Qthread

Comment: Run your code in a terminal or prompt to get further debug output: one thing that will certainly appear is a warning about destroying a QThread while the thread is still running, because you're always overwriting `self.thread_heandler` (and `self.new_heandler_message` along with it), which is obviously wrong. On a separate point, you should really avoid editing pyuic generated files (there is a clear warning on top of them, which you completely disregarded and removed); please follow th official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)

Comment: Note that Qt provides the QSerial API, which is asynchronous and allows you to avoid unnecessary threads.